# Can't figure out where this extra space is coming from

Tags: html, css

I have a video and a container for that video. However, I can't get the container to wrapper completely around the video. I've made the contrainer background white to clearly demonstrate where it's too big. The reason I need to to wrapper correctly is because I have a set of video controls which is now below the video where the wrap end. [image]

This is the CSS I've written and I've tried quite a few things but I just can't figure it out:

```
#video_container{
    -webkit-box-flex: 1; 
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    border:2px solid blue;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color:white;
}
#video_container video{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#video_container:hover #controls {
    opacity: 0.7;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

This is the HTML for the container:

```
<div id="video_container">
    <video id="trailers">
        <source src="vLast.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="vLast.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
    <nav>
       <div id="controls">
            <button id="playButton">Play</button>      
            <div id="defaultBar">
                <div id="progressBar"></div>
            </div>
            <button id="vol" onclick="level()">Vol</button>
            <button id="mute">Mute</button>
            <button id="full" onclick="toggleFullScreen()">Full</button>
        </div> 
       <div id="playlist">
            <div>cats</div>
            <div>cats</div>
            <div>cats</div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I think back when I did some HTML5 video stuff I had similar issues. Is it the same in ALL browsers?

Comment: Yea it happens for all of them.

Comment: actually it's much worst in Firefox. The wrapper goes all the way to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yeah, I don't remember if I every got it fixed, but I remember some issues. Hope you find your answer.

Comment: Did you try to add display:block on video element?

Comment: Thank you soooo much! As if it was that simple. I've been at it all day. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add display:block on the video element:

```
    #video_container video{
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        display:block;
 }
```

Comment: The display block fix the issue I was having with IE and Chrome so that's great. But with Firefox I get this which I am now trying to solve: http://jumpshare.com/v/eVjkFF?b=37JbUG